# ORDER BY RAND() returns duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried using distinct as well and it returns duplicates.

```
$cubes = mysql_query("SELECT distinct * FROM posts ORDER BY RAND() $limit ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I just want to take my posts table... and return it in a random order without duplicates.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select only the distinct id's you need, e.g.

```
SELECT distinct id FROM posts ORDER BY RAND() $limit
```

`Distinct` works over 'all' rows you select, so if you (for example) have a unique timestamp field, chances are you'll return every single row.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to execute a `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ...` and not just a `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM ...` ?

See the [SQL DISTINCT STATEMENT doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) for more infos.